# audio continuously playing even it moves to the next activity

Tags: android

I made an `activity` that has an audio as a background music. When i add a skip button to move to another `activity` the background music of my first activity was continuously playing. Here's my code, kindly check and post what should i add to my code. Thanks in advance!

```
public class pgone extends Activity {
    protected boolean _active = true;
    protected int _splashTime = 7000;
     public void onAttachedToWindow() {
            super.onAttachedToWindow();
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);


        }

     MediaPlayer audio;
     MediaPlayer SLONE;

    private long splashDelay = 6000; 


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pgone);

        TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
        {

            public void run() {

                Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(pgone.this, pgtwo.class);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
                finish();

            }

        };

        final Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(task, splashDelay);


        audio = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.storyaud);
        audio.start();

        SLONE = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.sl1);
        SLONE.start();


        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.buttonbeep);
        final Vibrator mVibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);


Button skipButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.skip);
skipButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent skipIntent = new Intent(pgone.this,choose.class);
        startActivity(skipIntent);
         mp.start();
         mVibrator.vibrate(500);
        finish();
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();


    }
});

    }

    protected void exitByBackKey() {

        AlertDialog alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setMessage("Do you want to exit the game?")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                finish();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            }
        })
          .show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stop the audio before moving to the next Activity. Try replacing mp.start() by mp.stop() here,

```
Button skipButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.skip);
skipButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent skipIntent = new Intent(pgone.this,choose.class);
        startActivity(skipIntent);
         mp.stop();
         mVibrator.vibrate(500);
        finish();
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();


    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Write `mp.stop()` `mp.reset()` instead of `mp.start()` on click event of skip button, and see below link for more information.

[Media Player example of Playing Sounds](http://www.badprog.com/android-mediaplayer-example-of-playing-sounds)

[Simple Android Mp3 Media Player](http://www.hrupin.com/2010/12/simple-android-mp3-media-player)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most efficient way  -

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        yoursMusicPlayerObject.release();

    }
```

Exploit Activity life cycle's onPause phase when you jump to next activity .Just release the I/O resources under use which is yours MediaPlayer object here .

Comment: @FrankN.Stein i editted it . No excuse just i was walking while typing . New to both stackoverflow and android . Thank you